# How can I write manually created http packets on the wire using Go to simulate a SPAN port?

Tags: go, packets

I'm needing to do some stress testing of an application I've written that takes packets from a mirrored port and processes them. I'd like to use Go to create a test harness that writes well-formatted, but otherwise random, HTTP packets on the wire, but I'm not sure how to do so without dialing a remote HTTP server before writing the packet.

Can someone point me in the direction of how to write raw data on the wire without needing to make a connection first? Is there a way in Go to treat a network interface as a generic I/O device and just write bytes to it?

Comment: What is an HTTP packet? It is a plain text protocol.  Do you mean HTTP2? Or do you mean make HTTP requests? If the second, then you can look at [net/http/Request](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Request)

Comment: HTTP doesn't have "packets", do you want to write raw TCP packets to the network? You can't get around dialing a connection, because TCP packets without an established connection aren't going to do anything. You can look at the [x/net/ipv4](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/net/ipv4) and [x/net/ipv6](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/net/ipv6) packages for some lower-level ip handling.